# Skewed Background with Angular components

Tags: html, angularjs, css

I'm facing a small design problem with CSS Adjustments. I skewed the backgrounds of all the sections and elements but near the footer, I want to join the article and footer it is not adjusting according to the design can any one please help how to fix it. Here is my plunker link.

```
<https://plnkr.co/edit/iCgonAiCoBUfSaAF851P?p=preview>
```

Comment: Add background-color: #6c7cd0 to your body.  That should get rid of the white space.  Note that your design will not look very good on very wide monitors... not much you can do about that without javascript.

Comment: If my article background color is white then how can i fix it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change CSS as the following

```
section {
background: #191919;
  color: white;
}
section, article {
  transform: skew(0deg, -10deg);
  padding: 20px;
}
section>div, article >div{
    transform: skew(0deg, 10deg);
}
article {
  background: white;
  color: black;
}
```

[Plunker Link](https://plnkr.co/edit/GO0txhdUom6mjNSh1o9r?p=preview)

Comment: I changed background-color of article still it has same problem  updated plunker link https://plnkr.co/edit/iCgonAiCoBUfSaAF851P?p=preview

Comment: How do you want the article section to be? white background with black font?

Comment: yeah with white background with black font

Comment: Sorry! What do you mean by new CSS?

Comment: I hope this is want you want https://plnkr.co/edit/GO0txhdUom6mjNSh1o9r?p=preview

Comment: Might be you missed the link I can't see there.

Comment: Yes, I cannot comment more here!

Comment: As I said I can't do because of fewer reputations. I'm new here. Sorry for that. Many are asking the same But I cannot do it!

Comment: yes I tried. It says I must have 15 reputations to vote up.

Comment: Not upvote. Can you see the tick mark just below the upvote/downvote buttons? Click that if the solution worked for you. Thats how you accept an answer

Comment: You never mentioned in your question that you wanted a white background for your article. Please understand that people put in time to fix issues for others, and you should have your ask properly documented in the first place. And if your requirements are changing, then you should update your original question, and upvote original correct answers.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in comments, add background color to your body and add some margin-top to the footer, and use the following CSS:

```
body, html {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    background:#191919;
}
.hero-image {
  background-color: #6c7cd0;
  padding: 200px 0;
  transform: skew(0deg, -10deg);
  margin-top: -150px
}
.hero-text {
  transform: skew(0deg, 10deg);
  text-align: center;
}

.wrapper {
  transform: skew(0deg, -10deg);
  background: #191919;
  color: white;
}
section, article {
  transform: skew(0deg, 10deg);
  padding: 20px;
}
.wrapper::after{
  transform: skew(0deg, -10deg);
}

div > h1 {
  margin-top: 50px;
}
footer {
  text-align: center;
  background: #6c7cd0;
  color: white;
  margin-top:50px;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

Note: Your layout needs considerable work in larger viewports specific to the skewing problem.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I changed background-color of article still it has same problem  updated plunker link https://plnkr.co/edit/iCgonAiCoBUfSaAF851P?p=preview

Comment: Please try and use the CSS I have pasted above? See if it solves your problem?

Comment: As you said my layout don't work better in larger viewports. May i know the problem and what kind of solution I need to approach for that please help out?

Comment: How is this answer not meeting your needs posted in the question?

Comment: sorry I didn't get you.